# Trying to get polygon from road path

Tags: polygon, openstreetmap, spatialite, sqlite

i'm using SQLite + SpatiaLite and converted maps from OSM to sqlite data base format.

I'm trying to get a polygon from road.

First trying:

```
select 
s1.name, 
ConcaveHull(Collect((s1.geometry))) as s1_geo
from ln_highway as s1
where s1.name like '%road_name%'
```

It's only working when road have more than one lane. But it's polygon of centered paths of lanes. So it's false representation of road.

Second trying:

```
select 
s1.name as s1_name,
Collect((s1.geometry)) as s1_geo
from ln_highway as s1
where s1.name like '%road_name%'
```

It's showing multilinestring of centered path of road.

If i'll know width of road is there some way to make polygon from this multilinestring (path of road) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the answer by Sandro Furieri from SpatiaLite google group.

```
SELECT s1.name AS name, 
UnaryUnion(
Collect(
Buffer(s1.geometry, 0.00001 * ?2)
)) AS s1_geo
FROM ln_highway AS s1
WHERE s1.name LIKE ?1
```

where ?1 is `%road_name%`
and ?2 is number of lanes on road (in one way).